# Can I do with an XMPP/ ejabbered server?

Tags: c#, windows, azure, amazon-ec2, ejabberd

I'm just starting the process of installing XMPP on a windows machine, but before I get in the thick of it I want to confirm whether it can do everything I need it to.
What we need:

1. To be able to store information about users, have passwords, and small descriptions (I think I read that this can be done with vCards, just confirming).
2. Allow users to be able to create chat rooms which will probably never close. Eg. Chat room on the game Starcraft. Users can come and go as they please, and see past conversations (sort of like a real time forum).
3. Store properties about the chat rooms. Eg. Starcraft chatroom would have "topic = games, date created = 2011, etc".
4. Be able to move the whole thing in a few months. We're probably gonna change hosting at some point, and it will be important not to lose all the data.
5. Less important, but can I install it on a server such as Azure or EC2? I know ejabbered can cluster though, so this is more of just a cost reduction idea.

Would a window XMPP server be able to do this? Specifically we're looking for a license where we won't have to pay commissions.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do all of those things in Ejabberd but, some of them are probably crossing into the domain of a web app that interacts with Ejabberd rather than being implemented purely on a chat server.

1 (storing information about users) You should be able to do this through mod_vcard. More complicated things using PubSub.

2 (persistent chat rooms) Multi-user chatrooms (mod_muc) can be set as persistent, you can also set a very long history length on the room, and save your complete chat history to disk.

3 (properties on chatrooms) You can set the subject and some other properties about the room but, it's limited.

4 (be able to move server) Ejabberd can be configured to persist to disk (and does by default for most things.) It can also be dumped to a file manually. Importing a dump to a new machine with a different name is tricky but can be done.

5 (EC2 or azure) EC2 is no problem, haven't tried Azure.

(Azure/Windows/Licensing)
If you're concerned about Azure licensing, Ejabberd is better suited for Linux/BSD than Windows.